# Modeling nested structures and filtering them

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Total noob in NoSQL putting my hands on Firebase Database and some questions popped up when I needed to apply a filter to my database.

My structure is similar to this:

```
{
  "burgers": {
    "burg-one": {
      "name": " Burger One"
    },
    "burg-two": {
      "name": " Burger Two"
    }
  },
  "ingredients": {
    "bacon": {
        "name": "Bacon",
        "burgers": {
            "burg-one": true,
            "burg-two": true
        }
    },
    "fried-egg": {
        "name": "Fried Egg",
        "burgers": {
            "burg-two": true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to filter on all the ingredients that `burg-one` has. In Java, I tried the code below, with no success:

```
firebaseDatabase()
    .child("ingredients")
    .orderByChild("burgers")
    .equalTo("bacon")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...);
```

I have read a couple of answers here for similar problemas but I could no quite get the correct idea of what should I do here.

Is the correct way to model these relations having to duplicate the lists in both models that relate to each other? In this case having my `Burger` model like so:

```
{
    "burgers": {
        "burg-one": {
        "name": " Burger One",
        "ingredients": {
            "bacon": true,
        }
    }
}
```

This way I'd have to query for each element in `ingredients` to get it's data?

Any explanation about these questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up changing my structure and needing to add another series of requests to get a burger's ingredients list. Here's the result:

```
{
  "burgers": {
    "burg-one": {
      "name": " Burger One",
      "ingredients": {
          "bacon": true,
      }
    },
    "burg-two": {
      "name": " Burger Two",
      "ingredients": {
          "bacon": true,
          "fried-egg": true
      }
    }
  },
  "ingredients": {
    "bacon": {
        "name": "Bacon",
        "burgers": {
            "burg-one": true,
            "burg-two": true
        }
    },
    "fried-egg": {
        "name": "Fried Egg",
        "burgers": {
            "burg-two": true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

With that database, I have to make the following changes in my code:

```
// Query database to get all burgers and receive in a single value listener
firebaseDatabase()
    .child("ingredients")
    .orderByChild("burgers")
    .equalTo("bacon")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(burgersValueEventListener);

// Add received burgers to a list in the database listener
burgersValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            burgerList.add(child.getValue(Burger.class));
        }
    }     
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};

Burger burger = burgerList.get(0); // Get a burger to query its ingredients
// Retrieve the burger's ingredient list and query the database for each one it has with a listener
for (String ingredient : burger.ingredients.keySet()) {
    firebaseDatabase
        .child("ingredients")
        .orderByKey()
        .equalTo(ingredient)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ingredientValueEventListener);
}
// Receive each (separately) ingredient's details in the listener
ingredientValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Ingredient burger = child.getValue(Ingredient.class); // Do something with your ingredient
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
```

This works fine but I wish we had a simpler way to achieve the filtering but I understand that's how things work in the NoSQL database model.